# Oracle SQL pattern finding

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this specific statement:

```
WHERE c.name LIKE '%B%l%' or c.name LIKE '%L%b%'
```

What would be an alternative statement that does the same job but without using the keyword `LIKE`?

Comment: `REGEXP_LIKE` perhaps?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Is this just a code golf question?  Or are you, for example, trying to tune the performance of a query that is doing a table scan because that's the only way to resolve this sort of `like` predicate?

Comment: It's just a few query questions that we have to make a query statement for to try and match an output, that's all (:

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WHERE (INSTR(c.name, 'B') > 0 AND INSTR(c.name, 'l', INSTR(c.name, 'B')) > 0)
OR    (INSTR(c.name, 'L') > 0 AND INSTR(c.name, 'b', INSTR(c.name, 'L')) > 0)
```

or

```sql
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(c.name, 'B.*l|L.*b')
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4de3a980e113b62f5dfb58032f127803)*

Comment: The first alternate statement works like a charm, thank you so much!